# How do I add line-through text decoration for a list element when clicked in Angular? Also change completed from false to true in the array

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<h1>To Do List</h1>
<input #newTodo>
<button (click)="addTodo(newTodo.value)">Add Todo</button>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">{{todo.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'todo-app';
  todos:any;
  

  constructor(private service:TodoService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getTodos()
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.todos = response;
      console.log(this.todos)
    })
  }

  
  
  addTodo(title: string){
    
    this.todos.push({
      userId: 1, 
      title, completed: false
      
      
    });
    console.log(this.todos)
  }
```

This is the code so far, would really appreciate help :D

I have tried going on youtube and several other websites to find a solution, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code you have so far. There doesn't seem to be anything in here relating to a click handler or styling for the strikethrough that you talk about. What is your question exactly? How to wire up a click event in angular or how to style the list item the way you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use ngClass directive. Drive it through true/false.

Answer (score 0):

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-djgaws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

```
<h1>To Do List</h1>
<input #newTodo>
<button (click)="addTodo(newTodo.value)">Add Todo</button>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">{{todo.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'todo-app';
  todos: { title: string; userId: number; completed: boolean }[];

  ngOnInit() {
    of([{ title: 'one', userId: 0, completed: false }]).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.todos = response;
        console.log(this.todos);
      }
    );
  }

  addTodo(title: string) {
    this.todos.push({
      userId: 1,
      title,
      completed: false,
    });
    console.log(this.todos);
  }

  markAsDone(todo: { title: string; userId: number; completed: boolean }) {
    todo.completed = true;
  }
}
```

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.strikethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a property to each `todo` called `isDone`, or something similar.
2. Define a function `toDoClicked()` or similar, and put `(click)="toDoClicked(todo)"` in your `li` line
3. Add a conditional class `[ngClass]="{'strikethrough-styling': toDo.isDone}` also to the line

When you're done, the HTML line should look like:

`<li *ngFor="let todo of todos" (click)="toDoClicked(todo)" [ngClass]="{'strikethrough-styling': toDo.isDone}>{{todo.title}}</li>`

You'll need to define a `strikethrough-styling` class, and you might need to use `<a>` tag instead of `li`, I don't remember if `li` has `(click)` binding.